# Flask 2 session abort

Tags: python, flask

I have 2 mode of sessions in Flask
1. 'admin'
2. 'normal'

This code

```
if 'admin' not in session:
    abort(404)
```

works... but if I "or-ed" the 2 sessions:

```
if 'admin' or 'normal' not in session:
    abort(404)
```

both aborts. I also tried

```
if 'admin' not in session or 'normal' not in session:
    abort(404)
```

it also aborts

Answer (score 0):

Try use `any`.

```
if not any(mode in session for mode in ('admin', 'normal')):
    abort(404)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that "works" vs. "not works" means:

```
"works" == "doesn't abort"
```

and

```
"not works" == "aborts"
```

So, from your examples:

Example 1:

```
If 'admin' not in session:
```

If this does not abort, then "admin not in session" is False. It looks for a key "admin" in the session dictionary, and finds it. You have a key called 'admin' in the session. The "not" negates this so you don't abort.

Example 2:

```
If 'admin' or 'normal' not in session
```

what happens here is

```
If 'admin' or 'normal'
```

evaluates to True, so this expression actually looks for a True (boolean) key in session. You indicate that this aborts, which implies that at some point you must have assigned a value to the True key.

That's a bit weird (no offense) so there must be some problem with the logic somewhere in your code.

Example 3:

```
if 'admin' not in session or 'normal' not in session
```

Python's logical "or" works like "evaluate the first term, then if that evaluates to True return it, else return the second term"

The first term is just example 1 (which we determined evaluates to False), so if it aborted it must have evaluated the second term as True. In other words,

```
'normal' not in session
```

is True, therefore if it aborted you can conclude that there is no key 'normal' in the session.

Now, storing modes as keys would allow multiple modes to be applied at the same time, which is probably not what you want.

You seem to be treating the session object as a set, but it is basically just a dict. If you have multiple modes, you should consider using a single key called 'mode', then store the current mode as the value for that key.

Then you could use simple logic like:

```
if session['mode'] == 'admin'
    ...
```

or

```
if session['mode'] == 'normal'
    ...
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Wooow. That really helped me. Thaaanks!

Comment: Excellent, glad it helped. Good luck.

Comment: BTW - did it help enough to answer your question? If so, you can accept any time... ;-)